# Sharepoint Workbench problem

Tags: web-part, error, sharepoint-framework

I did the first part of the [Sharepoint Framework tutorial](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part). Everything was good until the last step. At the end of this topic, we have to access to the SharePoint hosted workbench. When I tried, I arrived on a page with this error message:

> "Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred."

Do I have to configure something to access to it? Do you have a solution to avoid this error?

Comment: I have got a strong hunch the issue comes from the tenant you have used. The tenant must be created as "Office 365 Developer". See also [this](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant).

Comment: I've used it with a production tenant but the site needs to be created with the developer template.

Comment: @moe this is currently true for SPFx Extensions only. Client Web-Part development can be done in a regular tenant.

Comment: @theChrisKent I can't say anything from my own experience, but by referring to the link I provided in the comment, it's documented that one should create exactly a Office 365 Developer before moving on to creating the client-side WPs.

Comment: My web application has well a Developer site template. I don't know if itis what you want to know ? My other problem is I can't upload web apps on my site, problem occurs with this error message : /n "There were errors when validating the App manifest."

Comment: "To build and deploy client-side web parts using the preview release of the SharePoint Framework, you will need a normal Office 365 tenant". In addition, SPFx for Client-Side Web Parts has already reached General Availability and is no longer a preview release.

Comment: I didn't indicate, but I'm a new SharePoint user. I don't understand what is the difference between a Tenant and a Web application. And I don't know how create an Office 365 Tenant. Can you explain it to me please?

Answer (score 0):

You were right, the tenant must be created as Office 365 Developer.

To do this :

- Create a trial account on Office 365
- Sign in
- Click on Admin > Right menu panel > Admin centers > Sharepoint

Here you will see default site collections you can use to access to your workbench and upload your webparts.